# Why multiple instances of Method object are for the inherited methods

Tags: java, reflection, jvm

I discovered that classes with default equals method has different
instances of meta object Method. Why is it so? 
At first glance it looks not optimal because method objects are immutable.

```
class X {}
Method defaultM = Object.class.getMethod("equals", Object.class)
Method xMethod =  X.class.getMethod("equals", Object.class)

xMethod != defaultM
xMethod.equals(defaultM)
```

Comment: I don't think there's any theoretical reason, it probably just isn't an optimisation that would bring much improvement in practice for its price.

Comment: Try to convert both to string, if they belong to different classes, their string representation should be different.

Comment: What does Method objects being immutable have to do with it being non-optimal?

Comment: @EJP I think the argument is that they could therefore share the same instance.

Comment: @biziclop Do you mean *be* the same instance?

Comment: @EJP Yes. I have to say I see no technical reason why this couldn't be done, I just don't think there would be much to gain.

Comment: @biziclop Another question is whether `Method` objects are singletons at all, for the same method in the same class. If not, the question is futile anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Method` objects are *not* immutable. Since Java 2, `Method` extends `AccessibleObject`, which has the [`setAccessible(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-boolean-) method.

So not only do methods have a mutable property, this flag has security impacts which disallow sharing of `Method` objects.

Note that under the hood, `Method` objects do share their common immutable state via a delegate object, so what you get from `Class.getMethod` is just a cheap front-end object consisting of that mutable flag and a reference to the shared canonical method representation.

Answer (score 2):

The following code prints `false` even for two `Method` objects that refer to the *same* `Method` in the same class:

```
Method m1 = A.class.getMethod("equals", Object.class);
Method m2 = A.class.getMethod("equals", Object.class);
System.out.println(m1 == m2);
```

It is therefore idle to expect singleton behaviour for `Method` objects referring to methods in two *different* classes.

Answer (score 0):

Equals method of object is not final, it should have been reimplemented by your X class.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: what do you mean?
He ask why their is two differents equals method.
 I say the class X should have reimplemented the equals.

He say that's not possible because all the method of Object are immutable. 
I say it's not true, and because equals have not the final marker.

Comment: He asks why there are two different `Method` objects for two classes where there are *not* two different `equals()` methods. And he does **not** say that all the methods of `Object` are immutable. Read the question.